# IE7 throwing jQuery's 'Stack overflow at line: 0' error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, stack, overflow, preload

I have a small script on jQuery 1.7.2. Essentially, it displays the thumbnail, and then is replaced with the full image once that has loaded.

```
<img src="http://site.com/thumbnail.jpg" data-original="http://site.com/original.jpg"  class="preload">
```

Within jQuery, I simply have:

```
$('.preload').load(function(){

     $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("data-original"));

});
```

Which works fine on browsers such as Firefox, Chrome, and even IE8. However, IE7 will continue to throw a

```
Stack overflow at line: 0
```

Error (multiplied by the number of elements that have the preload class).

If I remove the class from the images.. the error is not shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing onload event on image and then chanign the image SRC so onload will fire again. its in infinite loop so you are getting stack overflow.

```
  $('.preload').load(function(){
    if($(this).attr('src') != $(this).attr("alt")){
         $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("alt"));
    }
  });
```

Comment: On FF and other browser also ebhaves same way but only thing is they stopped execuion after certin time. so if you use firebug or ctrl+shift+j in FF you will see stack overflow in it.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I assumed that it was probably an infinite loop, but just couldn't determine why. Goes to show that dated browsers can still have some uses, such as spotting mistakes such as. I'll be sure to take a peep at the FireFox shortcut you mentioned.

Thanks again